# How to get all items with a certain property in pivot table with eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a 'favourite' functionality for my loops table. I am trying to achieve this with a pivot table. But now I'm trying to find the most efficient way to call all the logged in users favourited loops with eloquent.

**loops table :**

```
    Schema::create('loops', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 35);
        $table->string('loop_path', 255);
        $table->string('FK_user_id');
    });
```

**users table:**

```
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('password', 60);
    });
```

**favourites table :**

```
    Schema::create('favourites', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('FK_user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('FK_loop_id')->unsigned();
    });
```

**Loop.php :**

```
class Loop extends Model {

    protected $table = 'loops';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','FK_user_id','id');
    }

    public function favourites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'favourites', 'FK_loop_id', 'FK_user_id');
    }

}
```

**This is how I achieve this now , but it doesn't seem efficient :**

```
    $loops = Loop::with('favourites')->
                   with('user')->get();

    $favouritedLoops = array();

    foreach($loops as $loop) 
    {
        //check if logged in user has favourited this
        $user_favorites = Favourite::where('FK_user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('FK_loop_id', '=', $loop->id)
            ->first();

        if ($user_favorites != null)
        {
            array_push($favouritedLoops, $loop);
        }

    }

    return Response::json($favouritedLoops);
```

Comment: Do you mean like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `favouritedLoops` method in `User` model, then You can easily access all favourited loops.

**User.php**

```
public function favouritedLoops()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Loop', 'favourites', 'FK_user_id', 'FK_loop_id');
}
```

and return now will look like:
`return Response::json(Auth::user()->favouritedLoops);`

Comment: I get this error when i'm trying this : Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'favourites' (SQL: select `favourites`.*, `favourites`.`FK_user_id` as `pivot_FK_user_id`, `favourites`.`FK_loop_id` as `pivot_FK_loop_id` from `favourites` inner join `favourites` on `favourites`.`id` = `favourites`.`FK_loop_id` where `favourites`.`FK_user_id` = 1)

Comment: whoops :) There was a mistake in my code, fixed now.